# changing pixel color with setPixel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a b/w picture I need to edit pixel by pixel. If a pixel too dark it's color should be changed to black. Here's my code:

```
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            pixel_value = int(hex(self.img.pixel(i, j))[8:], 16)

            if pixel_value < 110:
                self.img.setPixel(i, j, .......)
```

So the problem is I don't know how to pass a color to setPixel(). AFAIK it should be something like

```
self.img.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(0, 0, 0))
```

I'm using PyQt5.12.3 and I don't know how to import qRgb. PyQt5.QtGui only has qRgba64. If qRgba64 is also ok for setPixel() then how do I pass black color with qRgba64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the problem that you point out strange because if there exists the class qRgb in PyQt5 5.12.3 (I have also tested it in PyQt5 5.13.0):

```py
image.setPixel(i, j, QtGui.qRgb(0, 0, 0))
```

But anyway, if you want to use [setPixelColor()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setPixelColor-1) and convert the QRgba64 to QColor:

```py
image.setPixelColor(i, j, QtGui.QColor(QtGui.QRgba64.fromRgba(0, 0, 0, 255)))
```

Or better to use QColor:

```py
image.setPixelColor(i, j, QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: thank you! And the problem is in pyCharm I guess. It says that something is wrong with qRgb (it shows red underline)  but it still works fine when I run the program

Comment: PyCharm has bugs when trying to get information about some classes of PyQt5 so do not disregard it